# Problems with sound in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Since a power outage that turned my computer off unsafely, I lost the audio output on my Ubuntu installation.

ALSA is able to find the device:

```
$ aplay -l
**** Lista di PLAYBACK dispositivi hardware ****
scheda 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], dispositivo 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
```

I'm interested in the last one, since my HDMI monitor does not have speakers.

If I use ALSA to play some file, it works fine:

```
aplay -D plughw:1,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

However, the generic audio device listed above doesn't appear in the system audio settings, see image below:

[image]

and pulseaudio cannot find it either:

```
~$ pactl list short sinks
127 alsa_output.pci-0000_26_00.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le ch 2 44100 Hz SUSPENDED
```

I tried to `dpkg-reconfigure pulseaudio` and to remove the configuration files with no luck.

If I start from a Live USB Ubuntu, the audio card works just as fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you installed `pavucontrol` and looked to see if it can be found/set in there - or if it's already in there and muted?

Comment: Yes, I did, and I only see the HDMI device as above